# Preventing current window from following onlick/.click() link when ctrl+ or middle clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, window.location

I'm using an onclick event to make an entire div a navigable link.  This works well, until you use ctrl+click or middle-mouse click in order to open the target in a new tab.  I find that a new tab does indeed open, but so does the current tab.

See what I mean by ctrl+clicking on one of the boxes here: http://mw.modhistory.com/download-1

I don't want to interrupt the ability to browse normally by always forcing it into a new tab...the user should have the option here.  But I'd like to be able to quickly open a dozen of those links in new tabs without having to go "back" repeatedly.

I had what I thought was a brilliant idea to use preventDefault(), but that ended up doing the opposite of what I had in mind and entirely prevented the ability to open a new tab (which makes sense once I really thought about what it is meant to do.)

Any ideas?  Thanks!

--Fligg

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that either your event listener is sending events off to a routing/assigning function, or there aren't a whole lot of click events that you're looking to implement that AREN'T for this feature.

Either way, you can do something like:

```
// Assuming we already know what the purpose of the click was, and its target
function (e) {
    if (!!e.ctrlKey) { /* CTRL was held during mouse-click */ }
    else { /* not held */ }
}
```

As for mouse-buttons, they're pretty messed.

You should be fine using either:

```
e.which /* 1-based: middle-button is #2 */
```

or

```
e.button /* 0-based: middle-button is #1 */
```

Keep in mind that past support for figuring out which buttons were which was REALLY bad over the years.
If you've got a library that does the abstracting, use that.
Otherwise, other than offering this functionality to people with newer browsers, or compiling the previous values of which and button, it ends up at parsing browser versions, which is never, ever good.